# How to access data given pointer?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm trying to learn C and having trouble accessing the data from a pointer of the data.

I have the example code:

```
// character array for string
char mystring[] = "Hello";

// store mystring's pointer
int p = *mystring;

printf("String to pointer is %d\n":, p);
>> String to pointer is: 1819043144

// trying to access data from pointer p
printf("%s",&p);
>> H
```

Why does this just "H" just get printed when I try and access the data from pointer p using the & operator?

Comment: You're causing undefined behavior. The argument for `%s` has to point to a null-terminated string. `p` is an integer.

Comment: is &p not the data at the pointer address (ie. "Hello")?

Comment: No. `&p` is the address of the `p` integer variable.

Comment: You seem to be confusing `int *p = mystring;` with `int p = *mystring;`.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `&p` has nothing to do with `mystring`. `p` is an integer variable, and `&p` is the address of that variable.

```
int p = *mystring;
```

is equivalent to:

```
int p;
p = *mystring;
```

`*mystring` is the first element of the `mystring` array, which is the character `'H'`. So this is equivalent to:

```
int p = 'H';
```

Your variable initialization is simply making a copy of the first character of `mystring` and putting that in `p`. It also converts it from a `char` to `int`.

When you try to print `p` using `%s` format, you're causing undefined behavior, because `%s` requires the corresponding argument to be a pointer to a null-terminated string, and you've given it a pointer to an `int`.

Compare your code with this:

```
int *p = mystring;
printf("%s", p);
```

This is closer to correct, because now `p` is a pointer, and it does point to the string. It's not a copy of anything. But it's still incorrect because the argument for `%s` must be `char *`, not `int *`. So you need to convert it:

```
printf("%s", (char *)p);
```

But the most proper way to do it is the declare `p` as the correct pointer type in the first place:

```
char *p = mystring;
printf("%s", p);
```

Comment: I'd add the final step that shows the fully clean way [without the cast]: `char *p = mystring; printf("%s",p);` at the bottom